# Unpermitted parameter in rails 4 with dynamic params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Simple Form in a Rails application in which a FormsController controller was defined as follow :

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @forms = Form.all
  end

  def new
    @form = Form.new(form_params)
    @index = 1 # use 1 to test
  end

  ...

  private
    def form_params
      params.require(:form).permit(:user, :name, :tag, :link, :repo)
    end
end
```

Linked app view :

```
<div class="form">
  <%= simple_form_for @param do |f| %>
    <div class="form-inputs";>
      <%= f.input :user %>
      <%= f.input :name %>
      <%= f.input :tag %>
      <%= f.input :link %>
      <%= f.input :repo %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Create", class: "btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I made an http request with following parameters:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MAUm1zINofwLSiwGLsDD7RcZIpR52Z9RQZsNjiwrIASsshNIDUOycs2MkJH+tHvekWrmhk+4pMzmHvklZNmCMw==", "form"=>{"user"=>"val1", "name"=>"val1", "tag"=>"val1", "link"=>"val1", "repo"=>"val1"}, "commit"=>"Create"}

 (0.3ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "forms" ("user", "name", "tag", "link", "repo", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["user", "val1"], ["name", "val1"], ["tag", "val1"], ["link", "val1"], ["repo", "val1"], ["created_at", "2020-06-21 19:34:58.119471"], ["updated_at", "2020-06-21 19:34:58.119471"]]
 (5.8ms)  COMMIT
```

I modified the html name attribute using input_html option as follow :

```
   <div class="form-inputs";>
      <%= f.input :user, input_html: { name: "form[#{@index}][user]" } %>
      <%= f.input :name, input_html: { name: "form[#{@index}][name]" } %>
      <%= f.input :tag, input_html: { name: 'form[#{@index}][tag]' } %>
      <%= f.input :link, input_html: { name: 'form[#{@index}][link]' } %>
      <%= f.input :repo, input_html: { name: 'form[#{@index}][repo]' } %>
    </div>
```

From now, controller gets these parameters when a new form is submitted :

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bUGptr2P1hhn5DFsulxQW+Iy/W5aX/xASaxUKPTvdVrx9pwpgsHFlqEijftqKOhoZEE5fGw+x93uKaCDvB3XbQ==", "form"=>{"1"=>{"user"=>"val1", "name"=>"val1", "tag"=>"val1", "link"=>"val1", "repo"=>"val1"}}, "commit"=>"Create"}

Unpermitted parameter: 1
 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "forms" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2020-06-21 19:35:44.783270"], ["updated_at", "2020-06-21 19:35:44.783270"]]
 (0.5ms)  COMMIT
```

Data are no longer saved in the db due to unpermitted parameter. Is it necessary to add a specific entry to do the job ?

Comment: Why are you passing your @index inside your form as parameter?

Comment: Because, I plan to duplicate the form I did that modification to ensure the parameters entered as input for a specific form can be identified. I imagine something like `"form"=>{"1"=>{"user"=>"val1"...},"2"=>{"user"=>"val1"...}...}`

Comment: Ooh.. then, I recommend you to put that index as a hidden input inside your form instead, but your current solution and my suggestion are not safe, since any user can modify that

Comment: Indeed any user could easily modify the html name.. Is there a more standard path to follow ?

Comment: I think the best solution is the hidden input, but always validating in your controller that you are accepting non risking attributes no matter if the user changes the index